# While writing data to cookie but few keys are missing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am writing some data to `cookie` for my application. Total of 9 keys are being written. But when I review cookie data I see few keys are not written successfully.

Cookie keys are seperated by *(star)

Any ideas why this happens? What can be done to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post some code? Are writing this cookie via ASP.Net codebehind or Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this tool [IECookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iecookies.html) for more detailed info about your cookies and in the meanwhile, it would be helpful if you specify some code to get a clue about what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Polyzos. Unfortunately this one is not a approved software in my organization. I will put code used to write cookies

Comment: // Create a cookie with the specified name and value.
function SetCookie(sName, sValue)
{
  document.cookie = sName + "=" + escape(sValue);
  // Expires the cookie in one month
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
  document.cookie += ("; expires=" + date.toUTCString()); 
}

Comment: Following block of code is used to set cookie data.                   // Create a cookie with the specified name and value.
function SetCookie(sName, sValue)
{
  document.cookie = sName + "=" + escape(sValue);
  // Expires the cookie in one month
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
  document.cookie += ("; expires=" + date.toUTCString()); 
}